# How to print username for each alphabet letter

Tags: php

I have script where I try to print names following its alphabetical letter:

```
$alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$usersResult = getUsersEmail();
echo "<div class='m0'>";
echo "<div id=woohoo class=hey_im_here>";

echo '<input class="search" placeholder="Enter a name">';
echo "<br><br>";
$c=26; //or count(alphabets)
$count = count($usersResult);
for ($ii=0;$ii<$c;$ii++){
  echo "<div id='memberList$ii' style='display:inline-block;vertical-align:top'>";
  echo "<fieldset class=fieldname style='display:inline'>";
  echo "<legend class=name_legend>" . $alphabets[$ii] . "</legend>";
  echo "<ul class='list'>";
  while ($row_usrname = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult)) { 
    if (strtolower(substr($row_usrname['username'],0,1)) == $alphabets[$ii]) {
      echo '<li><label for="'.$row_usrname['username'].'">'
         . '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$row_usrname['username'].'" class="empCheckBoxClass" name="employment[]" value="'.$row_usrname['staff_id'].'" />'.$row_usrname['username'].'</li> </label>';              
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</fieldset>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

I am able to print names only for `A`:

[image]

How can I print it for every letter?

Comment: We might need to create a html table for it. Each column hosts a letter and all the names starts with it.

Comment: It would be better to extract your db results into an array, with the 1st letter as the array key. But if you keep this code, then you need to add a [mysqli_data_seek($usersResult);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) at the end of your loop to reset the internal pointer back to 0, in order to reloop through the results.